# ComboBox initial dropdown very slow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an object hierarchy with two levels. Something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<Child> Children{get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public object SomeOtherData{get;set;}
}
```

And then, in my VM,

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Parent> Parents{get;set;}
    public Parent SelectedParent{get;set;}
    public Child SelectedChild{get;set;}
}
```

The number of `Parent`s is about 4-5. The number of `Child`s per `Parent` usually is about 1500 (Though this can be exceeded). There are say, 20 or so `ComboBox` combinations in a `Window`. One combination would look like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsPanel="{StaticResource VSP}" ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParent}" x:Name="CbParents" />
    <ComboBox ItemsPanel="{StaticResource VSP}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedParent.Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedChild, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Here's the `ItemsPanelTemplate` for the `ComboBox`s:

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VSP">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Of course, there is one instance of `ViewModel` per this combination of two `ComboBox`.

The object hierarchy is loaded at program start up and does not change after that. Now, I do this:

1. Run program
2. Select a `Parent` from first `ComboBox`. The drop down menu shows immediately.
3. Try to select an item from second `ComboBox`. It takes roughly 2-3 seconds for the drop down to appear.
4. After the initial drop down, consecutive drop downs are fast.

The above is for a single combination of `ComboBox`s. The same lag for drop down happens for others. This is unacceptable. The lag can be tolerated if it is only for a single combination. But not for all. Ideally there shouldn't be any lag.
What can I do to improve the initial drop down performance?

EDIT : One small thing. At load-up, after the object hierarchy is created, for each `ViewModel` I load a `SelectedParent` and a `SelectedChild` from a file. So even before user tries to get the drop-down on a `ComboBox`, it already has a selected item. Does this change anything?

Comment: Does virtualization actually work? Try to spy the number of elements loaded in the second combobox on the first drop down open.